# Rename file on image upload

Tags: php

I am trying to rename the file to a random characters.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
{
    $path = "images/equipment/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);


    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {     
    }
}
```

The full path being output is images/equipment/headset.jpg for example

Answer (score 1):

To rename the file to random characters, you can use the `uniqid` function in PHP which generates a unique ID based on the current time in microseconds.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
{
    $path = "images/equipment/";
    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $newFileName = uniqid() . '.' . $ext;
    $path = $path . $newFileName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        // File uploaded successfully with new name
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to security issues you should additionally check for the extension and allow only a specific set.